# sudo password for installation

Tags: drivers, sudo, scanner, canon

I'm a quite new user of UBUNTU and when I try to install my Scanner Canon Lide300 under UBUNTU 20.04.2 LTS, 64-bit GNOME 3.36.8. in the Terminal I'm always asked by the system to add the sudo password.
Who is able to help me to get a member in the sudouser group?

Comment: It's your password, assuming you're the single user of that system. If not and your user hasn't such privileges then you need to ask who has them to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You choose your password when install the OS. The sudo password is the same as the password you enter when logging in. If you are not a sudoer and you have root password, you can add yourself to sudoer group.
first, log in as root. then open terminal and type this command:
`usermod -aG sudo {your username}`

You can check group of your user with this command:
`groups {your username}`

And you can change your password with this command:
`passwd {your username}`